# Understanding Bayesian inference

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I do have some experience with measure-theoretical probability, but fundamental statistics is not my forte. I have just realized that I might have had a wrong impression about how exactly Bayesian inference may help us.

As far as I understood, it definitely does help you in the following setup. Let's say you have $X \sim P_X =  \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where the parameters have some specified prior distributions $\mu\sim P_\mu$ and $\sigma \sim P_\sigma$. In case we see an update $X = x$, we can update $P_\mu\to P'_\mu$ and $P_\sigma\to P'_\sigma$ using Bayesian inference to accomodate for the new info. In this case posterior distributions $P'_\mu,P'_\sigma$ would depend both on the observed data $x$ and on the corresponding priors $P_\mu, P_\sigma$.

What I wonder about is the following setup though. Let's say again you're given **some** $P_X$, just some particular single measure. You further observe a draw $X = x$. How can we use Bayes to update $P_X$ based on what we just have seen? In general of course we would see multiple draws $\{X = x_i\}_{i=1}^N$, but I guess for starters just one draw is sufficient to analyze.

Comment: Allow me to suggest you try the procedure with an example and on paper for a simple example, yourself.  It seems to me that in your questioned case, you're missing a crucial part of the Bayesian, namely the parameters of the distribution that you want to update. You do need to have prior distributions for those parameters, as you yourself correctly described in the first part of your description. I think the dilemma will be unveiled if you exercise a simple example for yourself.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi *you're missing a crucial part of the Bayesian, namely the parameters of the distribution that you want to update. You do need to have prior distributions for those parameters* Why are they crucial? That's my point. What stops one from using Bayesian techniques for the last problem I've written down?

Comment: That is why I mentioned, you should examine by yourself. Simply explained, the theorem requires that you have a prior probability distribution on a random variable, to which you apply the information gained from a set of data (also a distribution over a random variable) this transition is manifest in the conditional probability distribution of the second (data) conditioned to the first (belief) and results in a new belief (posterior), a transition which is a probability distribution of the prior belief conditioned to the data. Next step: posterior is the next prior.